# OOP PHP error while connecting

Tags: php, oop

**Database file**

```
define("DB_HOST","localhost");
define("DB_USER","faizy");
define("DB_PASS","faizy");
define("DB_NAME","gallery_db");
?>
```

**Database Class**

```
<?php
    class Database {
        public $connection;

        function __construct() {
            $this->open_db_connection();
        }

        public function open_db_connection() {
            $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

            if(mysqli_connect_errno) {
                die ("database fails badly" . mysqli_error());
            }
        }
    }

    $database = new Database();
?>
```

**Template**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">
            Dashboard <small>Statistics Overview</small>
        </h1>

        <?php
            if($database->connection) {
                echo 'true';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Error**

> Notice: Undefined variable:
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

I am using object oriented PHP and trying to give connection eror in a simple template,But is is giving another error discuss below, Can anyone suggest or resolve my problem and i have done all the includes and all

Comment: Please edit your code. DO you have `$` in `database = new Database();`? Do you have proper open and closing php tags?

Comment: yes i am having $ in database and also having proper open tags

Comment: Did you include the database class to the template?

Comment: yes,i am just stuck from last 20 hrs,Can you please give me your mail address,ll mail u,file size is very small

Answer (score 1):

**Notice: Undefined variable** Error is because you are using mysqli_connect_errno in your Database class but `mysqli_connect_errno is a Function in PHP`, Hence replace mysqli_connect_errno with `mysqli_connect_errno().`

Comment: $database is object of my database class,Can you review my code

Comment: Have you checked that `$database` in a template has any value? Have you?

Comment: When you are including there files, Are they in right order ? Are you getting any line no. for errors ?

Comment: Yes i have checked,$database has no value in template

Comment: Check if $database in database class has value ? If no, there must be some connection error. Check if DB_HOST and other constant value are available ?

Comment: Yes the are in right order and line number is 9 in template

Comment: Everything is correct in my way,can you please give me email id,ll mail you,because m stuck in between,my file is onle 20kb

Comment: Thanks but now also it is not resolving i am just stuck from last 20 hrs,can you please eview it plzzzz prototype chain

Comment: I have tried your code. Its working fine at my end now. What else is the problem now ? Errors ??

Comment: Thanks for you effort bro

Answer (score 0):

try this , using $ before database, hope it will work

```
$database = new Database();
```